# Is it possible to recursively init git submodules without also updating them?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repository with a lot of submodules, and I would really like to recursively init all of them, configure a few to not update with 'git config submodule.<my submodule>.update none', then update everything I have not set to none with 'git submodule update --recursive'.

Is there a way to recursively init all submodules WITHOUT updating? 'git submodule update --init --recursive' will not work for me because the --init seems to override my 'git config submodule.<my submodule>.update none' setting.

Comment: There's no way to know what submodules a repo uses without fetching it, so how would you know what to set up?  You can only do it one layer at a time, i.e. not recursively.

Comment: But 'git submodule update --init --recursive' is able to recursively init AND update submodules without knowing what they are?  Am I confused about how that command works?

Comment: It can only init the recursive submodules because it has updated the current layer. You can't init submodules in a (submodule or not) repo you haven't fetched, because you don't know what those submodules are without fetching it.